# laravel artisan error while clearing config cache

Tags: php, laravel-5

when I run `php artisan cache:config` the command throw the following error

```
PHP Warning:  require(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/****/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 71
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/****/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 71
```

I have no idea what causing this and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns out that there is one suspicious file inside config folder, once it's deleted the artisan command works just fine again.

Comment: yup, I found a symlink in config folder , once I delete it and everything back to normal

Comment: Seems this... a well known problem :/ they use JPG to PHP to allow upload file and bypass laravel validation to allow upload file, to open a shell... what crazy... method..